# How to cleanup mangled/nested win8 user folders

Tags: windows-8, user-profiles, user-folders

I aborted an ssd drive scan by System Mechanic badly (not System Mechanic's fault), my default user profile got messed up, I created a new one, and now I have several user profiles.  The User Folders for one of these is messed up.  First, the User Folder shows at the same level as the C:\ drive.  Second, Under this User Folder appears a duplicate (if not exact, then close) user folder directly underneath.  I have not done an exhaustive comparison to test if the "sub" user folder matches the one above it, but I am inclined to delete one or the other, because it's using up lots of valuable space on my drive. When I took a deep breath and simply attempted to delete one, I got a warning asking if I knew what I was doing (ha ha!)  So rather than REALLY screw things up, I thought I'd ask:

- If I go ahead and delete this "sub" user folder:

  - will I really screw things up?
  - Is there a tidier way of doing this?
- How can I tell which of these User Folders is the one linked to the User Profile?
- Why is this folder not nested under C:\?
- Does that indicate another problem?

Many thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Take owership of the unused profile directory folders, transfer the data, then delete the directory.  We can't tell you why a user directory is located in the wrong location it your system.